# Windows CE 6.0 - USB Drivers at boot up time

Tags: windows-ce, driver, platform-builder

I built a new Windows CE image and placed two USB drivers. One for the USB printer and the second for some special device with digital and analog I/O ports.

I have one problem that came out with the drivers while the operating system boots up.

Every time the image boots up it asks to enter the driver's name. (The message is "Unidentified USB Device" Enter the name of the USB device driver) Is there a workaround for this problem ? What does I have to put into a registry?

I did not check if the driver is working after that because of my second problem
with the SQL CE 3.5 in my application.

The similar problem is happening if I not add a driver for example the Audio subsystem.
The OS at boot up scans the devices and finds some new hardware asking to fill the name for the driver.

It is simple to correct the second situation. I only have to check the item in the catalog view and rebuild the image. On behind the ragistry is filled with correct parameters but what am I supposed to do with custom drivers ?

Answer (score 1):

The "Unidentified Device" dialog happens when the USB node is queried and no macthing driver in the OS is found.  Which device, specifically, is causing that?  You mention both a printer and an I/O device - knowing which device is causing the error will help narrow it down.

When you "added the drivers" to the OS, did you just add the driver binaries, or did you also add the relevant registry entries in the drivers section? Those entries depend on the specific driver, so I can't tell you exactly which keys and values you need.

Comment: Actually I don't know which one is causing the problem. I think both because after canceling the first a second message box pops out so I concluded that both makes problems. When I added the drivers I added the binaries (2 dlls, one per driver). It is in project.bib. In the project.reg I put information about that I was told for the I/O driver only. For the printer I have not any information. The manufacturer didn't gave me any but I wanted to try. According to your response I suppose that I have to ask the printer manufacturer for the registry entries.

Comment: First thing to do is try each device individually.  Get one working, then the other, otherwise you've got no idea which is causing the problem.  Also, if the printer is a composite device (many are anymore), you might get a dialog for each function that it supports.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I have to break the problem into pieces and analyze it one by one. The printers for the Win CE are the main problem. The drivers and the support almost does not exist.

Comment: CE supports PCL printers fairly well.  Anything else, I find, and you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: I have a Star TSP100 USB printer that is said to be Win CE printer. I found the driver but no exact info about the registry entries. I am waiting the response from the support team. (http://driverscollection.com/?H=TSP100&By=Star%20Micronics&SS=Windows%20CE)